# Wireless Connection is slow but wired is fast (both through router)

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet

I was getting choppy internet especially when im playing a game or getting a video call. Was not sure of the issue.
I called up the ISP and they asked my to ping the Internet Gateway - when i noticed it was fluctuating a lot - going sometimes upto 300ms.

I'm noticing this behaviour only over wireless connections, and not wired. And its not happening to other devices connected wirelessly. Which is causing me to suspect something is wrong with my wireless adapter or something else (im really not sure).

Im on Ubuntu 18.04

Is there a way to diagnose or resolve this? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Wireless Adapter Details

```
vivek@xxx-0020:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 29
       serial: 7c:b2:7d:c8:32:cd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-108-generic firmware=34.3125811985.0 ip=192.168.1.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 30
       serial: f8:75:a4:1a:11:a2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.5-3 ip=192.168.1.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 memory:a1400000-a141ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: br-4828223669f5
       serial: 02:42:16:a7:4e:d5
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.19.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:86:f1:c3:f5
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Internet Gateway Ping results through wireless connection -

```
Wed Jul  8 15:53:24 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=127 ttl=63 time=11.2 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:53:34 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=128 ttl=63 time=10.9 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:53:44 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=129 ttl=63 time=102 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:53:54 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=130 ttl=63 time=82.9 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:54:04 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=131 ttl=63 time=87.7 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:54:14 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=132 ttl=63 time=12.4 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:54:24 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=133 ttl=63 time=10.5 ms
Wed Jul  8 15:54:34 IST 2020: 64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=134 ttl=63 time=5.49 ms
```

Internet Gateway Ping results through wireless connection (during video call) -

```
vivek@ideacrest-0020:~$ ping 10.12.212.129
PING 10.12.212.129 (10.12.212.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1407 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=1831 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=11 ttl=63 time=1680 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=12 ttl=63 time=1581 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=14 ttl=63 time=2990 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=17 ttl=63 time=1808 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=18 ttl=63 time=1758 ms
```

Internet Gateway Ping through wired connections -

```
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=29 ttl=63 time=1.52 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=30 ttl=63 time=0.948 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=31 ttl=63 time=1.30 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=32 ttl=63 time=1.50 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=33 ttl=63 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=34 ttl=63 time=1.10 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=35 ttl=63 time=0.962 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=36 ttl=63 time=1.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=37 ttl=63 time=1.03 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=38 ttl=63 time=1.00 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=39 ttl=63 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 10.12.212.129: icmp_seq=40 ttl=63 time=1.04 ms
```

Output of iwlist wlp5s0 freq

```
vivek@xxx-0020:~$ iwlist wlp5s0 freq
wlp5s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Oh missed that, using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Connect to your wireless and show me `iwlist wlp5s0 freq`. What channel is your router set to?

Comment: I suggest to atert with upgrading kernel to HWE. Run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04` and reboot.

Comment: @heynnema in the router its currently set to auto.

Have added output to the question.

Comment: @Pilot6 sure. Sorry for being noob, i couldnt find much info [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-generic-hwe-18.04), what would the update do? Thanks

Comment: The update will install the 5.3 kernel that may have improvements in `iwlwifi` driver. You will still be able to boot with the old kernel.

Comment: Does your router support 5GHz wireless? Your wlp5s0 wireless card does. If so, at least temporarily, switch to the 5GHz wireless network, and see if your problem goes away. If it does, it might give us a clue that there's an interference problem on the 2.4GHz wireless network.

Comment: @heynnema unfortunately no, im considering buying a new router

Comment: Do you have the WiFi Analyzer app on your smartphone? Or some other app to show channel usage in your area?

Comment: Is QoS enabled in your router?

Comment: I checked up on the channel usage - my Wifi is on channel 11 whereas there are 3 more in the range of 3.7. 
I do not see a QoS option in the router, assuming its not enabled.